# Why does multiplying by two works when converting fraction to binary

Tags: binary

I have the number **0.625**. If I need to convert it into binary form, I can multiply by two:

```
0.625 * 2 = 1.25 / 1
0.25 * 2 = 0.5 / 0
0.5 * 2 = 1.0 / 1
```

So the result is 0.625<sub>10</sub>=0.101<sub>2</sub>

I'm trying to understand how this algorithm works. The initial form is:
$$ x_1\cdot2^{-1} + x_2\cdot2^{-2} + x_3\cdot2^{-3} = 0.625 $$
I can factor out 2<sup>-1</sup>, so the I'll have:
$$ 2^{-1}\cdot(x_1\cdot2^0 + x_2\cdot2^{-1} + x_3\cdot2^{-2}) = 0.625 $$
From here:
$$ x_1\cdot2^0 + x_2\cdot2^{-1} + x_3\cdot2^{-2} = 1.25 $$
Now, what logic should I use to tell that x<sub>1</sub> is 1 here?

Comment: Think of running the algorithm on a *binary* fraction. It obviously works then!

Comment: @almagest, sorry, didn't understand your comment. Do you mind clarifying?

Comment: If you take a binary fraction like $0.101$, the repeatedly multiplying by 2 in the same way as for the fraction $0.625$ generates $1,0,1$.

Comment: yeah, thanks, my question was specifically about understing why x1 equals to 1 in the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know all of the $x_i$s are either $0$ or $1$. You also, hopefully know that the infinite sum
$$ (2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-3} + \cdots) = 1 $$
so in your final equation we have
$$ x_1\cdot 2^0 + \underbrace{x_2\cdot 2^{-1}+x_3\cdot 2^{-2}}_{\text{ at most }1} = 1.25 $$
Since the right-hand side is *larger than* $1$, the $x_1\cdot 2^0$ term must be nonzero -- and the only way to do that when $x_1$ is either $0$ or $1$ is to make $x_1=1$.

Comment: great, thanks, that's a good explanation. Do you know if that's what defines the algorithm? Or maybe there are other better explanations?